# How do I dump the entire contents of a json file into a div?

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

I would like to dump the entire json file into my div called container without accessing each item such as in container 2. Is there any way to do this? This is my javascript file.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var container = $("div.containerDatadump");
    var container2 = $("div.containerOutput");
    $("#get").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "data/directory.json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                container.append(data);
                $.each(data, function(index, item) {
                    $.each(item, function(key, value) {
                        container2.append(value + "<br/>");
                    });
                    container2.append("<br/><br/>");
                })
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Use a `<pre>` instead of a `<div>`, then use `$("your pre here").text(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4))` which prints the JSON object into it with indentation. Not sure whether that's what you're looking for though as the question is a bit vague

Comment: Change dataType to "text" and the data variable inside your success callback will be a string of JSON instead of a javascript object.

Answer (score 2):

`JSON.stringify` turns json into a string, which can then be printed using jQuery's `html()`.

```js
var container = $("#container");
$("#get").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      container.html(JSON.stringify(data, null, "<pre>    "));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="get">GET</div>
<div id="container"></div>
```

**EDIT:** To format the JSON, you can [pass a third parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Parameters) into `stringify()`.